# C# Updating log textbox while running

Tags: c#, loops, freeze

I have spent the past few days working on bot for an MMO.  It runs in one big loop, with 1-2 other smaller loops inside. So far its going great. When its running it is set to update a richtextbox with what it is currently doing, just so I can easily troubleshoot later.

My problem is while its active and looping it does not auto update the textbox until it has finished everything it is doing.  Which is hard when its set in an infinite loop.  I would like to be able to run the bot with the main program window on the other monitor giving me updates as it goes along.

The whole program seems to freeze up and I cant interact with it at all while running.  This also causes problems when I want it to stop.  The only way I have of stopping it at the minute is to click Stop in visual studio.

I have tried searching around, but I have no idea what to search for.  I hope I explained it well enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will most likely have to implement threading if you want this to be responsive...

The other option would be to have your main program write the log to a file/database and then have a separate program that reads that.

Comment: Not to keen on a separate program, but ty for threading.  It at least gives me something to type into Google.  Would you have any links to get me started?

Comment: Searching for title of your question should give you decent start... If you drop "UI freeze" into mix you'll get most of what you are looking for... At this point your question likely to be deemed off-topic as searching for tools/links...

Comment: I suggest you look at `BackgroundWorker` - it encapsulates a thread for you, and you can use the `ProgressChanged` event to pass updates back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a nice read : 
http://www.beingdeveloper.com/use-dispatcher-in-wpf-to-build-responsive-applications/

### To summaries

You can send in a delegate fx, which is responsible for a formatter or writter. In you implemetation it would be the one which does AppendText. and make sure the Richtextbox.AppendText is within Dispatcher.Invoke()

Code Sample

```
class BotRand
 {
   //Write Event is delegate
   public execute(WriteEvent writeFx)
    {
     //Crawl
     writeFx("message");
    }
 } 

 class MainWindow : Window
 {
      void WriteFunc(object message, EventArgs outline) 
       {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => richText.AppendText(message));
       }
 }
```

This should help you start your search more effectively.
Thanks,